# Webform is not rendered

Tags: c#, webforms

I have this simple webform which shows list of files stored in database and Download link for each file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="LLPIposAttachment.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>iPOS Attachment</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            font-family: Arial;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h2>iPOS Attachments List</h2>
        </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="AttachmentList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ATTACH_NAME" HeaderText="File Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="DownloadFile" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ATTACH_ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Label ID="lbMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <!-- log part -->
        <asp:Label ID="lbLog" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <!-- log part -->
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I want to add one special case. Where only one file is present in database, I don't want to show Grid, but only message in Label, that there is only one file, and automatically download this file. I try to do it, actually file is downloaded but webform is not rendered at all.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace LLPIposAttachment
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string bujn;
        string[] param;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["BUJN"] != null)
                {
                    bujn = Request.QueryString["BUJN"].ToString();
                    param = bujn.Split('_');
                }
                else
                {
                    param = new string[2];
                    if (Request.QueryString["BU"] != null)
                    {
                        param[0] = Request.QueryString["BU"].ToString();
                    }
                    if (Request.QueryString["JN"] != null)
                    {
                        param[1] = Request.QueryString["JN"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inputSqlCon"]);
                sqlCon.Open();
                string inputSql2 = @"SELECT count(*) 
                 FROM PA_REQ_NOTE_ATTACHMENTS atta join PA_REQ_INVOICES inv  on atta.NOTE_ID = inv.NOTE join " + param[0] +
                 "_A_SALFLDG ldg on ldg.TREFERENCE = 'IP ' + CONVERT(varchar(12), INV_NO) and ldg.ACCNT_CODE = inv.SUPPLIER_ACCNT_CODE " +
                 "where inv.SUN_DB = '" + param[0] + "'and D_C = 'C' and ldg.JRNAL_NO = " + param[1];
                SqlCommand sqCom2 = new SqlCommand(inputSql2, sqlCon);
                SqlDataReader sqRead2 = sqCom2.ExecuteReader();
                sqRead2.Read();
                int rowCount = sqRead2.GetInt32(0);
                sqlCon.Close();
                if (rowCount > 1)
                {
                    BindGrid();
                }
                else if (rowCount == 1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sqlCon.Open();
                        inputSql2 = @"SELECT atta.ATTACH_ID, atta.ATTACH_NAME 
                         FROM PA_REQ_NOTE_ATTACHMENTS atta join PA_REQ_INVOICES inv  on atta.NOTE_ID = inv.NOTE join " + param[0] +
                         "_A_SALFLDG ldg on ldg.TREFERENCE = 'IP ' + CONVERT(varchar(12), INV_NO) and ldg.ACCNT_CODE = inv.SUPPLIER_ACCNT_CODE " +
                         "where inv.SUN_DB = '" + param[0] + "'and D_C = 'C' and ldg.JRNAL_NO = " + param[1];
                        sqCom2 = new SqlCommand(inputSql2, sqlCon);
                        sqRead2 = sqCom2.ExecuteReader();
                        sqRead2.Read();
                        string id = sqRead2.GetString(0);
                        string name = sqRead2.GetString(1);
                        lbMsg.Text = "File " + name + " was downloaded";
                        byte[] bytes;
                        string fileName;
                        string constr = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inputSqlCon"];
                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                            {
                                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT ATTACH_NAME, ATTACH FROM PA_REQ_NOTE_ATTACHMENTS where ATTACH_ID = @Id";
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                                cmd.Connection = con;
                                con.Open();
                                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    sdr.Read();
                                    bytes = (byte[])sdr["ATTACH"];
                                    fileName = sdr["ATTACH_NAME"].ToString();
                                }
                                con.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        Response.ClearContent();
                        Response.Charset = "";
                        string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
                        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;FileName={0}", fileName));
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
                        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e1)
                    {
                        lbLog.Text = e1.Message;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void BindGrid()
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inputSqlCon"]);
            sqlCon.Open();

            //live SQL
            //string inputSql = @"SELECT atta.ATTACH_ID, atta.ATTACH_NAME
            // FROM PA_REQ_NOTE_ATTACHMENTS atta join PA_REQ_INVOICES inv  on atta.NOTE_ID = inv.NOTE join " + param[0] + 
            // "_A_SALFLDG ldg on ldg.TREFERENCE = CONVERT(varchar(12), INV_NO) and ldg.ACCNT_CODE = inv.SUPPLIER_ACCNT_CODE " +
            // "where inv.SUN_DB = '" + param[0] + "' and ldg.JRNAL_NO = " + param[1];
            //live SQL

            //test SQL
            string inputSql = @"SELECT atta.ATTACH_ID, atta.ATTACH_NAME 
                 FROM PA_REQ_NOTE_ATTACHMENTS atta join PA_REQ_INVOICES inv  on atta.NOTE_ID = inv.NOTE join " + param[0] +
             "_A_SALFLDG ldg on ldg.TREFERENCE = 'IP ' + CONVERT(varchar(12), INV_NO) and ldg.ACCNT_CODE = inv.SUPPLIER_ACCNT_CODE " +
             "where inv.SUN_DB = '" + param[0] + "'and D_C = 'C' and ldg.JRNAL_NO = " + param[1];
            //test SQL
            SqlCommand sqCom = new SqlCommand(inputSql, sqlCon);
            SqlDataReader sqRead = sqCom.ExecuteReader();
            AttachmentList.DataSource = sqRead;
            AttachmentList.DataBind();
            sqlCon.Close();
        }

        protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string id = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
            byte[] bytes;
            string fileName;
            string constr = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inputSqlCon"];
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT ATTACH_NAME, ATTACH
                    FROM PA_REQ_NOTE_ATTACHMENTS 
                    where ATTACH_ID = @Id";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        sdr.Read();
                        bytes = (byte[])sdr["ATTACH"];
                        fileName = sdr["ATTACH_NAME"].ToString();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
            Response.ContentType = mimeType;
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: No, nothing shows in console at all.

Comment: @viveknuna Why would there be an error in the browser console if there is no javascript involved?

Comment: @GSerg I am just ruling out the possibilities? and how do you know javascript is not involved? HAs OP mentioned it?

Comment: @PavelMatras There is only one `Response`. You you use that `Response` for a file, it cannot also carry a web page to show.

Comment: @viveknuna Because this is ASP.NET Webforms, a [20 years old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Web_Forms) technology the code for which is presented above. It does not involve jacasript unless the code specifically invokes it, which it does not.

Comment: @GSerg Ok, and how can I process automatic file download and also show the page?

Comment: @GSerg I know that and I have used Asp.Net webforms also. but you cannot say the OP doesn't have JS if he has not mentioned in the question

Comment: @PavelMatras You return the page as normal and prepare the file for download on the server side, and in the returned page you include some javascript that downloads the prepared file.